# Is it possible to change the output location of NodeMcu error messages?

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

Currently all error messages are outputted to the console, which requires a USB cable to view. Is it possible to modify the firmware to send error messages to a remote server for logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "modify" you mean *configure* then the answer is no, not possible.

If, however, you mean *edit/alter* then yes, of course you can change the source. `NODE_DBG` and `NODE_ERR` which use `dbg_printf` in https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/app/include/user_config.h#L37 are a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks so much @marcel-stör! I did mean edit/alter. Where is dbg_printf defined?

Edit: Never mind I found it https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/app/libc/dbg_printf.c

Comment: If I make any changes to the NodeMcu firmware, is the only way to test those changes building the firmware and flashing it to the hardware?

Comment: Yes, there's no emulator or the like.

Comment: I'm using the Docker image and I've commented out the modules I don't want in user_modules.h but the file seems to be ignored. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: just to confirm, errors like "lua: ?:0: attempt to call field 'gets' (a nil value)" are outputted by dbg_printf?